# Problems in for loop (python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, compiler-errors, qtquick2

The for loop can run 33 times but can't run more than it.
I have to run it 100 times.
thank you!
The for loop has to run 100 times and in the end print "a" "profit" and "total"

---

```
a = 0
pluser = 0.01
total = 0
profit = 0
lasta = 0
lastProfit = 0
lastTotal = 0
counter = 0
for i in range (100):

        lasta = a
        lastTotal = total
        lastProfit = lasta * 14 - lastTotal
        a += pluser
        total += a
        profit = a * 14 - total
        while (profit <= lastProfit):

            pluser += 0.01
            a += pluser
            total += a
            profit = a * 14 - total
            counter += 1

print(a)
print(total)
print(profit)
print(counter)
```

Comment: It gets stuck in the while loop because the `profit` is always decreasing at the iteration 33. You are subtracting `total` from it.

Comment: Notice that `total` might be greater than `14a` in the while loop, and moreover, `total` might be increasing faster than `a`.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code I got an infinite loop because you are subtracting from profit, so it is always less than lastProfit which is equal to 0.

You may want to check what you're doing to profit in the loop, as well as your starting variables.

I hope this helps!

:)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works you can create a while loop and a new variable. You can set x = 1 and then each time it runs it will add one so it will complete after one-hundred times. Make sure the x + 1 is indented
`x = 1

While x <= 100:

x + 1`